# Connection reset by ::1 port 22 (Windows 10 + PowerShell/cmd + OpenSSH)

Tags: powershell, ssh, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh

I'm a host **Windows 10** (version 20H2, build 19042.746), with WSL2 installed (like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

After I installed the **OpenSSH** (like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse and https://www.hanselman.com/blog/the-easy-way-how-to-ssh-into-bash-and-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine), with these commands in **PowerShell as admin**:

```
> Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent

> Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
> Start-Service sshd
> Get-Service sshd
> Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
> New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe"
> Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed
```

I checked that the Windows Firewall includes service OpenSSH as an active and open Inbound Rule.

I checked with telnet too:

```
> telnet localhost 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
```

*Until here seems all is ok!*

**Now the problem happens**, running the command also in **PowerShell** (or in **cmd**):

```
> ssh localhost
Connection reset by ::1 port 22
```

**Did anyone have the same problem (running in: Windows 10 + PowerShell/cmd + OpenSSH)?**

**Does anyone know why this problem happened?**

**Does anyone know how to solve this problem?**

Thanks!

> **============= MORE INFOS =============**

Follow another command to debug:

```
> sshd -d
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: key_load_private: Permission denied
debug1: key_load_public: Permission denied
Could not load host key: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug1: key_load_private: Permission denied
debug1: key_load_public: Permission denied
Could not load host key: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug1: key_load_private: Permission denied
debug1: key_load_public: Permission denied
Could not load host key: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
```

The `__PROGRAMDATA__` seems to refer to Windows environment variable `%PROGRAMDATA%`, that point to `C:\ProgramData`.

```
> ls C:\ProgramData\ssh

    Diretório: C:\ProgramData\ssh


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        25/01/2021     19:59                logs
-a----        27/01/2021     02:03           2252 sshd_config
-a----        25/01/2021     19:59            668 ssh_host_dsa_key
-a----        25/01/2021     19:59            628 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-a----        25/01/2021     19:59            227 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-a----        25/01/2021     19:59            200 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-a----        25/01/2021     19:59            432 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-a----        25/01/2021     19:59            120 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-a----        25/01/2021     19:59            420 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Follow the content from sshd config:

```
> cat C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\sshd_config_default
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server

Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

Comment: What happens when you run `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` directly from PowerShell and cmd?  Any errors there?  Try just reversing one change - The registry key addition with that command.  Does it work then (albeit to cmd, rather than bash)?

Comment: Yes, the same error occurs in both: PowerShell and cmd (without running `bash`).

If I run `bash` command firstly, as it results enter inside the guest Ubuntu system, then if I try to make an `ssh localhost` connection, in fact, I'm trying to enter in the same guest machine (Ubuntu), instead of the host Windows with OpenSSH Server.

I want to connect to the host Windows, not to the guest Ubuntu.

The connection to the guest Ubuntu works perfectly (including from host Windows).

Comment: Having the same issue, any updates?

Comment: The same problem continues:

`>ssh localhost`
`Connection reset by ::1 port 22`

`> telnet localhost 22`
`SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1`

Comment: Hello, have you figured out the issue? It is happening to me as well.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1027#issuecomment-359449663
Maybe can help us! I will check.

Comment: @FabrícioPereira Did it help? I still face this issue.

Comment: Hi @KartikRaj, I haven't been able to solve this problem yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing same issue and fixed. Need to move extracted Open-SSH folder to Program Files and it works properly.

Comment: Can you give me more details about this procedure?

Comment: I downloaded the Open-SSH.zip into Downloads folder. I installed the .ps1 from there too. After experiencing error, I uninstall using .ps1 script, copy paste the whole folder into C:\Program Files\ (my installer was x64), and then re-run install .ps1 script from there. Then it worked, no more error appearing.

Comment: I did the same thing that Water mention (by executing this Powershell Script: https://gist.github.com/fabriciorsf/b4744551a48a76f1ae6ecae597b2c488 ), but the same error remains.
But I had a little progress, because now from a remote machine the same error happens (before from a remote machine I had received the error of 'Connection timed out').

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue that the connection was reset on the Windows 10 with Win32-OpenSSH.

The ssh client log as below.

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\OpenSSH-Win64> .\ssh.exe my_host -v
OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.2p1, LibreSSL 3.7.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/config line 19: Applying options for my_host 
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\test1 type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\test1-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.2
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:22 as 'user'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 127.0.0.1 port 22
```

And the sshd log as below

```
11852 2023-09-05 16:56:17.715 debug3: fd 6 is not O_NONBLOCK
11852 2023-09-05 16:56:17.716 debug3: spawning "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\OpenSSH-Win64\\sshd.exe" -R as subprocess
11852 2023-09-05 16:56:17.745 debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 10 config len 2204
11852 2023-09-05 16:56:17.745 debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
11852 2023-09-05 16:56:17.745 debug3: send_rexec_state: done
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.784 debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.785 debug3: process_channel_timeouts: setting 0 timeouts
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.785 debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.785 Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 60777 on fe80::bb34:1c60:9c70:3825%17 port 22
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.785 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.2
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.785 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.2
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.785 debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.786 debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.797 debug3: spawning "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\OpenSSH-Win64\\sshd.exe" -y as user
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.808 debug2: Network child is on pid 11584
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.808 debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 6 config len 2204
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.808 debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.809 debug3: send_rexec_state: done
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.809 debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.809 debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.809 debug3: preauth child monitor started
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.820 debug3: mm_request_receive: entering
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.820 debug1: do_cleanup
1664 2023-09-05 16:56:17.820 debug1: Killing privsep child 11584
11852 2023-09-05 16:56:17.829 debug2: pselect_notify_done: reading
```

As you can see, the connection is established but no authentication is performed. The sshd.exe is spawning to a subprocess successfully, but getting killed after the mm_request_receive is entering without any error message. If I have use the `sshd -d` to run the sshd in debug mode, it worked well; however, running as the service-daemon does not. The main different is the privilege for running the sshd process, it is the `user` for the debug mode and the `SYSTEM` for the service-daemon.

After the trial and error, I have found out that the permission of your `OpenSSH-Win64` folder, it must have the `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated User` role with the `read and execute` privilege. And the `sshd.exe` must have the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` role with the `read and execute` privilege.

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\OpenSSH-Win64> icacls .
. NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\OpenSSH-Win64> icacls .\sshd.exe
.\sshd.exe NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Also, I will suggest to comment out the match group setting in the `sshd_config` file. In case your sign-in user is in the administrators group that it will be authenticated by the `__PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys` file and it might be a little bit confused that the AuthorizedKeysFile is whether the `%userprofile%/.ssh/authorized_keys` or not.

```
#Match Group administrators
#       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** what worked for me was generating a public/private key pair on my client machine with `ssh-keygen` and then adding my id_rsa.pub contents to `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`. I also stopped the sshd service with `Stop-Service sshd`, and now I manually run sshd in a command prompt window.

**Tips for debugging the issue:**
Similar to other answers, I diagnosed the issue on my machine by stopping the sshd service via `Stop-Service sshd`, and then manually running sshd in debug mode by opening a new CMD prompt and executing `sshd -d`.

Now when you try to ssh into the machine, you see logs for where there might be a failure. In my case, my machine was attempting to read `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`, but this file did not exist. Creating it and adding my client's id_rsa.pub to it resolved the issue.

After you solve the issue, I recommend just running `sshd`, without the `-d` flag in the future. (`sshd -d` will terminate after a single connection).

Similar to other answers, I'm still not sure show to get this working with `Start-Service sshd`, but manually running `sshd` works for my purposes.